# Why can't a data member be in a lambda capture list

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a class `foo` that has `bar` as a member variable.

In another member function of the class, I'm writing a lambda function:

```
[bar](void){}
```

But I can't include `bar` in the capture list. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure it is related to the member being `const`?

Comment: Actually, no. It fails for all members. I'll amend the question.

Comment: I fixed the title for you.

Comment: Oops. That's a beer I owe you if you're ever in Mayfair.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You capture class members by saying `this` in the capture list. This has nothing to do with the fact that the member is `const`.

---

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    const int a = 0;
    int b;
    Foo() : b{42} {
        auto f = [this]() { std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl; };
//                ^^^^ 
        f();
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo x;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. If you specify `this` in the capture list, you are capturing the value of the `this` pointer, NOT the value of the  class members. What you have will compile and work much of the time , but what you have is not thread safe. The values of `a` and `b` can change after the lambda is created but before it is evaluated.  See the other answer from Casey to make it thread safe.

Comment: It is the programmers choice if he wants a copy or a reference.

Comment: You are correct, but in the original question, the OP was trying to catch `bar` by value, not reference.  Catching the `this` pointer by value catches the member variable by reference.

Answer (score 54):

Only objects with automatic storage duration can be captured by a lambda in C++11 (i.e. local variables and function parameters). If you want the effect of capturing a `non-static` class data member, you can either capture the `this` pointer as in [Danvil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803240/923854):

```
auto f = [this]{ std::cout << a << std::endl; };
```

or cache the data member's value in a local variable and capture that:

```
auto a = this->a;
auto f = [a]{ std::cout << a << std::endl; };
```

which will be much more concise in C++14:

```
auto f = [a = this->a]{ std::cout << a << std::endl; };
```

The choice between these two options depends on whether you want to store the value `a` has *right now* or if you want to retrieve the value `a` has *when the lambda is called*. Note that in the case where `this` is captured you must ensure that the lifetime of the pointer object encloses the lifetime of the lambda a call to the lambda after the object is destroyed has undefined behavior. The more simple case that captures a copy of `a` is completely self-contained and has no such lifetime issues.

Comment: But using `[this]` is not the same as using `[a = this->a]` - or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Danvil Correct. `[a = this->a]` captures a copy of `this->a`, but without requiring an intermediate copy like the 2-line C++11 version that caches `this->a` in a local.

Comment: Does auto const& a = this->a; save one copy?

Comment: `auto f = [&a = this->a]{ std::cout << a << std::endl; };` would also work if you want to capture by reference.

Comment: Is `&a = this->a` a reference of the original member `a`?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's worth to add the following very clear example which works since C++14, I really prefer this approach to capturing the whole this pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct A 
{
    int a;
    function<void(int)> change = [&a = this->a](int param){
        a = param; // I only captured by ref because of this
    };
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.a = 100;
    cout<<a.a << endl; // output 100
    
    a.change(50);
    cout<<a.a << endl; // output 50

    return 0;
}
```